# jacoco maven plugin not reporting test coverage

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I am trying to use jacoco with maven. When I run mvn clean test I expect the coverage output to be written to target/coverage-reports however when I open up index.html after the build it's empty.

I checked the following,
- The jacoco.exec file is present and it has a bunch of class names in it
- In the coverage html there is a link 'Sessions' when I click on it I see a bunch if my classes that seem to have been executed
- I see no errors or warnings when I run the maven command

I'm puzzled as to why the report is empty. From all the examples I have seen it seems like this should work. What am I missing?

I am using the following jacoco configuration for the maven plugin

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <append>true</append>
      <skip>false</skip>
      <excludes/>
      <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/</outputDirectory>
      <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
      <includes>
        <include>mypackage.*</include>
      </includes>
      <check>false</check>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>pre-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>post-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>test</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

### UPDATE

Apparently this has something to do with the includes pattern that I have provided. When I remove the includes it does show me coverage but for more than I need. I'm still trying to figure out the pattern to use to do a proper include.

Answer (score 2):

You need to hook it to surefire as well, change it to

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.3.201306030806</version>
            <executions>
              <!-- pre-unit-test execution helps setting up some maven property,
                which will be used later by JaCoCo -->
              <execution>
                <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                  <!-- passing property which will contains settings for JaCoCo agent.
                    If not specified, then "argLine" would be used for "jar" packaging -->
                  <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <!-- report phase setup -->
              <execution>
                <id>post-unit-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <!-- output file with report data. -->
                  <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                  <!-- output directory for the reports. -->
                  <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>

          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-test</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>test</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
              <argLine>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m</argLine>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Jigar, I do have surefire setup that way. It still does not work.

Comment: try feeding the report to some parser, I am not exactly sure the file you are referring to should have html formated data that you are expecting

Comment: This config works well, I've just tried it on my workstation.

Comment: Please could you expand this answer? I read this several times and still have absolutely no idea what line is relevant and what it is that I need to do to link unit/integration test mojos with Jacoco.